# PHP - preg_match()

Tags: php, preg-match

This code prints "Got match" if the string can be matched in the /$reg/. Is is possible for me not just to match but display all the possible strings from that regular expression. Like for example my regular expression is "(a|b)*" possible strings are aaaa, abbb, bbbb, bbbaa, etc. I want to print all of those with the maximum length 5.

```
if(isset($_POST['calc'])){
$reg = $_POST['regex']; 
$str = $_POST['str'];

if (preg_match("/$reg/", $str)) 
{
    echo "Got match!";
}

else 
{
echo "String not valid";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unset($matches);
if (preg_match_all("/$reg/", $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) 
{
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
if (preg_match_all('/\b[ab]{1,5}\b/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo implode(', ', $matches[0]);
}
```

This finds all strings of sequential "a" or "b" characters up to a maximum length of 5.

Comment: Thank you sir, can I ask a question? If this finds all strings of sequential "a" or "b" how come there is still an string in the parameters ($str). what string should I put there?

Comment: @John `$str` is the subject of the search